# some terminologies on limiting mixed hodge structures or rather Derived categories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

[image]

$f: X\rightarrow S$ is proper surjective homomorphism map from connected complex manifold to unite disk. $Y=f^{-1}(0)$ is algebraic and normal crossing in X, f is smooth away from 0, $X^*=X\setminus Y$.

we have above assumptions in Steenbrink's paper "limits of hodge structures".

I have some questions about the terminologies he uses.

in lemma (4.6), he says that the sequence: $i^{-1}\mathbb{R}j_*\mathbb{Q}_{X^*}(-1)[-1]\rightarrow i^{-1}\mathbb{R}j_*\mathbb{Q}_{X^*}\rightarrow i^{-1}\mathbb{R}j_*\mathbb{Q}_{X^*}(1)[1]$ is exact in derived category of abelian category of sheaves of $\mathbb{Q}$-modules over $Y$, i.e $D^+(Y, \mathbb{Q})$， where$(n)$ is multiply $(2\pi i)^n$, $[n]$ is shift of complex, morphism is get from cup product with $f^*(dt/t)$, t is parameter in S, it should be clear if we take $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficient singular cochain resolution of $\mathbb{Q}$. This is quite clear for me. I think he just means that the above sequence is an exact triangle with transfer functor to be (3)[3] instead of usual shift by 1, since we can use Kozul complex to show the corresponding induced long cohomology sequence is exact.

However, in lemma(4.8). he mentioned that we have  the sequence $i^{-1}\mathbb{R}j_*\mathbb{Q}_{X^*}(-1)[-1]\rightarrow i^{-1}\mathbb{R}j_*\mathbb{Q}_{X^*}\rightarrow (i^{-1}\mathbb{R}k_*\mathbb{Q}_{\tilde{X}^*})_{un}\rightarrow 0$, is exact in the derived category $D^+(Y, \mathbb{Q})$, where $(i^{-1}\mathbb{R}k_*\mathbb{Q}_{\tilde{X}^*})_{un}$ is the maximal subobject of the nearby fibre $i^{-1}\mathbb{R}k_*\mathbb{Q}_{\tilde{X}^*}$ with unipotent monodromy action.  Here it is very strange to say that it is exact, because we can not make it into triangles. Also we have no kernel, coker, injective\surjective morphism in Derived category. So my question is how to make sense of "a complex is exact in a derived category". There is only one way, i.e it form an exact triangle ? I am not quite sure What does the term mean in 1976's paper.

And also in (4.9), he says that $(i^{-1}\mathbb{R}k_*\mathbb{Q}_{\tilde{X}^*})_{un}\rightarrow i^{-1}\mathbb{R}j_*\mathbb{Q}_{X^*}(1)[1]$ is an injective map. Here how to make sense of "injective map in a Derived category"?

Comment: Hi Feng, I agree that talking about exact sequences in this context doesn't make sense, but I think  that Steenbrink meant that these sequences can be realized by  exact sequences of complexes. Try to take a look at discussion of limit MHS in the book by Peters and Steenbrink, and see if that clears anything up.

Comment: Dear Donu, Thank you for your suggestion. I should read that part in the book to make more sense.  :-)